# cocos2dx ccDrawLine gradient color ?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

I am making a drawing application where I want user to allow gradient color when they draw line .. ccDraw allows the color but how to get gradient color ?

Comment: You have to implement this yourself.

Comment: @ReckHou : so how do i implement it. I mean give me some idea i will work around with those things